# Selecting descendant based on classes

Tags: html, css

Element type descendant selection works:

```
form * div {...}
```

but I find that using classes does not:

```
.my-class1 * .my-class2 {...}
```

I.e. I expect a few elements to be selected by the "class descendant" selection form, but none are.

In my page I have two very similar DOM sub-structures generated by third party code that needs different styling, and I don't want my CSS to relying on that third party DOM structure.

What is the best way to style these two parts of the DOM?

Comment: There is no reason `.my-class1 * .my-class2` should not work - both selectors are equally valid, as you would expect. The problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.my-class1 > .my-class2` to direct descendants.

Or you can use `.my-class1 .my-class2` for any `.my-class2` that is descendant of `.my-class1`.

Comment: Brutal! It sounds like `form * div` is a long version of `form div`? Or does it only apply to classes/ids?

Comment: this is basic CSS. you should avoid using wildcard selector `*` , , so this `form * div` or this `form  div` does the same

Comment: the `*` means *any element* so the particular line you're referring to selects all `my-class2` that's under any other element, and that element is under `my-class1`. I agree with @dippas that using `*` is a bit smelly.

Comment: @JonasByström Yes, you can do `form div`. Look at the point 5.5 of the [reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors)

Comment: @dippas, `form * div` is *almost* the same as `form div`. The latter one allows the `div` to be a direct child of `form`, whereas the former one requires an (any) intermediate element.

Comment: @Chris Yes, at it puts in the specs: _The following selector: `div * p`  matches a P element that is a grandchild or later descendant of a DIV element_

Comment: @Chris: There is absolutely nothing wrong with using `form * div` when the * is not at the end of the selector. Besides, what would you suggest as an alternative, assuming overriding is not feasible for reasons outside of the author's control?

Comment: @BoltClock, Oh, I didn't say it was wrong to use it. I was referring to `*` in general, not as it was presented in this post. Perhaps I should've made that more clear. However, I still prefer other approaches than using `*`, if possible, even if it's not the key selector. But that's just personal preference.